# Change slideshow speed CSS

Tags: css, slideshow

I currently have a slideshow on my website but it is sliding too fast, I would like to make it slower but I dont know how can I do that, everytime I try to change some things I end up ruining everything.

I wanted to get like 5/6 seconds each slide.
I would be extremely grateful if someone could help me.

```css
.topSlider {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute; }

  .topSlider span {
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center; }

  .topSlider .slide {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-animation: slide 12s infinite;
    animation: slide 10s infinite;
    overflow: hidden; }
  .topSlider .slide:nth-child(2) {
    left: 0%;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -1s;
    animation-delay: -0.5s;
    background-color: black;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center; }
  .topSlider .slide:nth-child(3) {
    left: 100%;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    background-color: red;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center; }
  .topSlider .slide:nth-child(4) {
    left: 100%;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
    animation-delay: 4.5s;
    background-color: white;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center; }
  .topSlider .slide:nth-child(5) {
    left: 100%;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
    animation-delay: 7s;
    background-color: blue;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center; }
  .topSlider p {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 340px;
    color: white; }

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  0% {
    left: 100%;
    width: 100%; }
  5% {
    left: 0%; }
  25% {
    left: 0%; }
  30% {
    left: -100%;
    width: 100%; }
  31% {
    left: -100%;
    width: 0%; }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
    width: 0%; } }

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    left: 100%;
    width: 100%; }
  5% {
    left: 0%; }
  25% {
    left: 0%; }
  30% {
    left: -100%;
    width: 100%; }
  31% {
    left: -100%;
    width: 0%; }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
    width: 0%; } }
```

```html
    <div class="topSlider">
        <div class="slide"></div>
        <div class="slide"></div>
        <div class="slide"></div>
        <div class="slide"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the seconds

```
    -webkit-animation-delay: -1s;
    animation-delay: -0.5s;
```

for each child.

but also make sure that the main slider time is proportional to the interval between the seconds in the slider children. Have a look at my example below and compare it to yours to see what I mean.

main slider time in your example:

```
-webkit-animation: slide 12s infinite;
animation: slide 10s infinite;
```

```css
.topSlider {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute; }

  .topSlider span {
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center; }

  .topSlider .slide {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-animation: slide 20s infinite;
    animation: slide 20s infinite;
    overflow: hidden; }
  .topSlider .slide:nth-child(2) {
    left: 0%;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -1s;
    animation-delay: -0.5s;
    background-color: black;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center; }
  .topSlider .slide:nth-child(3) {
    left: 100%;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
    animation-delay: 4.5s;
    background-color: red;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center; }
  .topSlider .slide:nth-child(4) {
    left: 100%;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
    animation-delay: 9.0s;
    background-color: white;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center; }
  .topSlider .slide:nth-child(5) {
    left: 100%;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 15s;
    animation-delay: 13.5s;
    background-color: blue;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center; }
  .topSlider p {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 340px;
    color: white; }

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  0% {
    left: 100%;
    width: 100%; }
  5% {
    left: 0%; }
  25% {
    left: 0%; }
  30% {
    left: -100%;
    width: 100%; }
  31% {
    left: -100%;
    width: 0%; }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
    width: 0%; } }

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    left: 100%;
    width: 100%; }
  5% {
    left: 0%; }
  25% {
    left: 0%; }
  30% {
    left: -100%;
    width: 100%; }
  31% {
    left: -100%;
    width: 0%; }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
    width: 0%; } }
```

```html
    <div class="topSlider">
        <div class="slide"></div>
        <div class="slide"></div>
        <div class="slide"></div>
        <div class="slide"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.
I just tested it and the time for each slide is perfect, but there is a problem, the 1st slide to the 2nd is perfect, but the 2nd to the 3rd and the 3rd to the 4th is not working properly and in the end it has an "extra" slide without anything with like 2 seconds

Comment: I just figured out what was wrong, now everything is perfect, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can change the duration part of the `-webkit-animation` and `animation` properties ("2s"):

```
 -webkit-animation: slide 2s infinite;
animation: slide 2s infinite;
```

```css
.topSlider {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute; }

  .topSlider span {
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center; }

  .topSlider .slide {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-animation: slide 6s infinite;
    animation: slide 6s infinite;
    overflow: hidden; }
  .topSlider .slide:nth-child(2) {
    left: 0%;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s;
    background-color: black;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center; }
  .topSlider .slide:nth-child(3) {
    left: 100%;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s;
    background-color: red;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center; }
  .topSlider .slide:nth-child(4) {
    left: 100%;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s;
    background-color: white;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center; }
  .topSlider .slide:nth-child(5) {
    left: 100%;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s;
    background-color: blue;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center; }
  .topSlider p {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 340px;
    color: white; }

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  0% {
    left: 100%;
    width: 100%; }
  5% {
    left: 0%; }
  25% {
    left: 0%; }
  30% {
    left: -100%;
    width: 100%; }
  31% {
    left: -100%;
    width: 0%; }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
    width: 0%; } }

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    left: 100%;
    width: 100%; }
  5% {
    left: 0%; }
  25% {
    left: 0%; }
  30% {
    left: -100%;
    width: 100%; }
  31% {
    left: -100%;
    width: 0%; }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
    width: 0%; } }
```

```html
<div class="topSlider">
        <div class="slide"></div>
        <div class="slide"></div>
        <div class="slide"></div>
        <div class="slide"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: But that makes it too fast, I want to slow it down, I want each slide to take more time

Comment: You can put the duration you want.